# Vim does not load plugins in edit window but loads them in help or other system windows

Tags: vim, plugins, statusbar, vundle

### Background

I wanted to use some vim plugins (used it plain vanilla before). I installed
`vundle` (my `.vimrc` is at the bottom).

I ran `PluginInstall` and it went ok, `PluginList` shows:

```
" My Plugins
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'sjl/badwolf'
Plugin 'itchyny/lightline.vim'
Plugin 'tomtom/tcomment_vim'
Plugin 'easymotion/vim-easymotion'
Plugin 'nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides'
Plugin 'junegunn/fzf'
```

### Problem

When I open vim, the status bar from lightline does not show. However, if I do
`:help` or `:PluginList`, these windows have the status bar from lightline.

This has been driving me insane and I have uninstalled/installed vim countless
times now, to no avail, so any help will be hugely appreciated!

#### `.vimrc`

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

Plugin 'sjl/badwolf'
Plugin 'itchyny/lightline.vim'
Plugin 'tomtom/tcomment_vim'
Plugin 'easymotion/vim-easymotion'
Plugin 'nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides'
Plugin 'junegunn/fzf'
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
```

Comment: How do you know the plugins are not loaded? If its the statusline, have you checked `:help 'statusline'` ? You may need to set it to 2

Comment: there is no :help statusline. The plugins ARE loaded, they are just not working in the edit window.

Comment: You wrote—`the plugins are not loaded`—can you [edit] to clarify how you know the dont work?

Comment: Also, running `:help statusline` in my vim takes me to a file in vim similar to [this one](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'statusline')

Comment: I said "in the edit window". They are definitly loaded in vim, as if I do :help, I get a window with the plugins loaded and PluginsList shows them all. However, in the edit window they are not working/not loaded, I don't know which. I am currently running the apt version of vim, 7.x as installing 8 did not help. Perhaps yours is 8?

Comment: `statusline` is not new with 8 (though if you have `vim.tiny`—default, I believe on Ubuntu or similar—you may not have the help files). Until you [edit] to clarify what `not loaded` (direct quote) or `not working` (direct quote) means, it's going to be difficult to answer your question. I don't know if you're just expecting a statusline, in which case, see the help I've linked, or if you're running a plugin-provided command, and it's not having the expected behavior, or what.

Comment: Please try some of the steps in [this link](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file?r=SearchResults&s=1|36.0126) as well, if you have time. I'm stepping away now

Comment: You were right to point me to look better into what was happening. If you wish, make it into an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `:help 'laststatus'`

(In the comments, I mistakenly pointed the OP towards `'statusline'`.)

> `'laststatus'` `'ls'` number  (default 1)
>
> The value of this option influences when the last window will have a status line:
>
> - 0: never
> - 1: only if there are at least two windows
> - 2: always
>
> The screen looks nicer with a status line if you have several windows, but it takes another screen line. `|status-line|`

The default value of `'laststatus'` means that the status line will only show if there are at least two windows, and it usually only shows up *in the last window*.

To show it always, add

```
set laststatus=2
```

to your vimrc.